# Module Federation Component causes React hydration error

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, webpack-module-federation

I have two application running locally.
My remote exposes the following component:

```
const Content: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {
    const [state] = useSharedState<number>('counter', 0);

    return (
            <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '50px', background: 'yellow' }}>
              vla <span>{state}</span>
            </div>
           );
};
```

This is my host component:

```
import Content from 'app2/Content';

export const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useSharedState('counter', 0);

    return (
        <div>
            <Helmet>
                <title>Hello World</title>
            </Helmet>
            <React.Suspense fallback={"loading"}>
                <Content />
            </React.Suspense>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    setState(0);
                }}
            >
                click button
            </button>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    setState((st) => st + 1);
                }}
            >
                submit an event <span>{state}</span>
            </button>
            <div>Hello {data && data?.hello}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

My setup runs React on an express server, which does serverSideRendering using `renderToPipeableStream`.

The SSR HTML looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title data-react-helmet="true">Hello World</title>
    <script async="" data-chunk="main" src="/static/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background: yellow">
                vla <span>0</span>
            </div>
            <button>click button</button><button>submit an event <span>0</span></button>
            <div>Hello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now for the client and initial render, this is the error message I get:

```
Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "vla " Client: "Hello "
```

To get a sense of what might be in my initial render, I thought about using renderToString just before hydrating, giving me the following code and HTML output on the client:

```
const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(app);
console.log(htmlString);

const container = document.querySelector('#app');
hydrateRoot(container!, app);
```

output:

```
<div><!--$-->
    <div style="width:100%;height:50px;background:yellow">vla <span>0</span></div><!--/$--><button>click
        button</button><button>submit an event <span>0</span></button>
    <div>Hello </div>
</div>
```

The entire application runs fine after render, and the two components can work together without issues. But it's a riddle to me why I'm getting a hydration error here. It must be related to the Module Federation Component, since the hydration errors disappear when removing the component from the tree.

This also makes sense with the error message which is shown.
The client doesn't see the component text "vla" which was present on the server. But immediately starts with "Hello".

There is also no flickering visible on render, so the transition from server html to rendered client component is seamless. Just without hydration.